# Regex expression to replace colon grouped integers into years, months, and days and drop leading zeroes

Tags: c#, regex

I'm pretty bad at Regex (C#) with my attempts at doing the following giving non-sense results.

Given string:  058:09:07
where only the last two digits are guaranteed, I need the result of:

"58y 9m 7d"

The needed rules are:

1. The last two digits "07" are days group and always present. If "00", then only the last "0" is to be printed,
2. The group immediately to the left of "07" which ends with ":" signify the months and are only present if enough days are present to lead into months. Again, if "00", then only the last "0" is to be printed,
3. The group immediately to the left of "09:" which ends with ":" signify years and will only be present if more then 12 months are needed.

In each group a leading "0" will be dropped.

(This is the result of an age calculation where 058:09:07 means 58 years, 9 months, and 7 days old. The ":" (colon) always used to separate years from months from days).

Example:

```
058:09:07  --> 58y 9m 7d
01:00 --> 1m 0d
08:00:00 --> 8y 0m 0d
00 --> 0d
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of the variable that stores the original data? Do you really have it as a string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. The age calculation is returned as as string from the server database. (PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can pretty much do this without regex.

```
var str = "058:09:07";
var integers = str.Split(':').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

var result = "";
switch(integers.Length)
{
    case 1:
        result = string.Format("{0}d", integers[0]); break;
    case 2:
        result = string.Format("{0}m {1}d", integers[0], integers[1]); break;
    case 3:
        result = string.Format("{0}y {1}m {2}d", integers[0], integers[1], integers[2]); break;
}
```

If you want to use regex so bad, that it starts to hurt, you can use this one instead:

```
var integers = Regex.Matches(str, "\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(x=> int.Parse(x.Value)).ToArray();
```

But, its overhead, of course. You see, regex is not parsing language, its pattern matching language, and should be used as one. For example, for finding substrings in strings. If you can find final substrings simply by cutting it by char, why not to use it?

Comment: Makes sense. I'm trying to learn Regex better, how to do this with Regex?

Comment: @AlanWayne: It will be much more complex with a regex, but similar to this one since you will have to analyze the optional parts in the regex match. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/XptWfo).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep. Thats where I keep getting hung up. :)

Comment: You can use a regex approach if you have these values inside longer strings. Else, this answer is all you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the demo. Can you add explanation please--I'm still trying to get the conditionals.  Thanks

Comment: @eocron06 Thanks. I was trying to match a variable pattern instead of parsing--my error! :)

Answer (score 1):

*DISCLAIMER*: I am posting this answer *for the educational purposes*. The easiest and most correct way *in case the whole string represents the time span eocron06's answer is to be used*.

The point here is that you have *optional* parts that go in a specific order. To match them all correctly you may use the following regex:

```
\b(?:(?:0*(?<h>\d+):)?0*(?<m>\d+):)?0*(?<d>\d+)\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3A(%3F%3A0*(%3F%3Ch%3E%5Cd%2B)%3A)%3F0*(%3F%3Cm%3E%5Cd%2B)%3A)%3F0*(%3F%3Cd%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cb&i=058%3A09%3A07%0D%0A01%3A00%0D%0A08%3A00%3A00%0D%0A00)

**Details**:

- `\b` - initial word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing optional group (see the `?` at the end below)

  - `(?:0*(?<h>\d+):)?` - a nested non-capturing optional group that matches zero or more zeros (to trim this part from the start from zeros), then captures 1+ digits into Group "h" and matches a `:`
  - `0*(?<m>\d+):` - again, matches zero or more `0`s, then captures one or more digits into Group "m"
- `)?` - end of the first optional group
- `0*(?<d>\d+)` - same as the first two above, but captures 1+ digits (days) into Group "d"
- `\b`  -  trailing word boundary

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/XptWfo) where the final string is built upon analyzing which group is matched:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pattern = @"\b(?:(?:0*(?<h>\d+):)?0*(?<m>\d+):)?0*(?<d>\d+)\b";
        var strs = new List<string>() {"07", "09:07", "058:09:07" };
        foreach (var s in strs)
        {
            var result = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, m =>
                m.Groups["h"].Success && m.Groups["m"].Success ? 
                    string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}d", m.Groups["h"].Value, m.Groups["m"].Value, m.Groups["d"].Value) :
                m.Groups["m"].Success ? 
                    string.Format("{0}m {1}d", m.Groups["m"].Value, m.Groups["d"].Value) :
                        string.Format("{0}d", m.Groups["d"].Value) 
            );
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```